# How to implement a script while saving a file in django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm new to django.
I want to run a script(for ex. zipping a file) after it gets uploaded to a server through "admin panel",i.e when user hits Save "in" from admin panel,it should get zipped(or some other manipulation that i may want to implement) after it gets uploaded.
Or can you just tell me which function is called when user hits the save button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals might work, but it seems like the OP wants to do something only when an object is created or changed *from the admin panel.*

I think the best way to do this is to use the ModelAdmin method `save_model()`.

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods):

```
ModelAdmin.save_model(self, request, obj, form, change)
```

You can overwrite this method in your definition of an admin class, as follows:

```
class SomeObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # do any pre-save stuff here
        obj.save()
```

The `change` arg is a Boolean value that is True if the object is being changed, and false if the object is being created for the first time. So if you want to execute some function only on object creation:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
           # do your compression here
           # do any other pre-save stuff here
        obj.save()
        # do any post-save stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use signals : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/
to detect the save action.